# create a counter based on condition in row value

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a counter that counts the occurrence of numbers.
For instance, lets say we have data like this

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(rep(seq(1:2),each=2),times=2)),gr=rep(c("A"),each=8))

  ID gr
1  1  A
2  1  A
3  2  A
4  2  A
5  1  A
6  1  A
7  2  A
8  2  A
```

Every time the data ends with `2` I would like to set counter. So the expected output

```
  ID gr  counter
1  1  A  1
2  1  A  1
3  2  A  1 
4  2  A  1  ~~data ends with 2
5  1  A  2
6  1  A  2
7  2  A  2
8  2  A  2  ~~data ends with 2
   1  A  3
   1  A  3
   2  A  3
   2  A  3  @@just for an example
```

I have tried this

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%
  mutate(counter=cumsum(ID==2))
```

but it seems to not even close to the desired output!

How can we do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `dplyr`:

```
# added one more row to your example
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(rep(seq(1:2),each=2),times=2),1),gr=rep(c("A"),each=9))

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(id=cumsum(c(0,diff(df$ID)) & lag(df$ID==2))+1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   gr [1]
     ID     gr    id
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
1     1      A     1
2     1      A     1
3     2      A     1
4     2      A     1
5     1      A     2
6     1      A     2
7     2      A     2
8     2      A     2
9     1      A     3
```

Comment: A variation: `df %>% group_by(gr) %>% mutate(group = cumsum(c(0, diff(ID == 2)) < 0) + 1L)`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(rep(seq(1:2),each=2),times=4)), gr= "A")
```

You can take an ID and see if it increased or decreased. In case of increase, say that this belongs to the same group. If not, reset group  (by increasing by 1).

```
group <- rep(NA, length(df$ID))
group[1] <- 1

for (i in 2:length(df$ID)) {
  if (df$ID[i] >= df$ID[i-1]) {
    group[i] <- group[i-1]
  } else {
    group[i] <- group[i-1] + 1
  }
}

df$group <- group
df

   ID gr group
1   1  A     1
2   1  A     1
3   2  A     1
4   2  A     1
5   1  A     2
6   1  A     2
7   2  A     2
8   2  A     2
9   1  A     3
10  1  A     3
11  2  A     3
12  2  A     3
13  1  A     4
14  1  A     4
15  2  A     4
16  2  A     4
```

If you are hell-bent on `dplyr`, you can turn this into a function.

```
library(dplyr)

findIncrSeq <- function(x) {
  group <- rep(NA, length(x))
  group[1] <- 1

  for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] >= x[i-1]) {
      group[i] <- group[i-1]
    } else {
      group[i] <- group[i-1] + 1
    }
  }
  group
}

df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(counter = findIncrSeq(ID))

# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   gr [1]
      ID     gr group counter
   <int> <fctr> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1      A     1       1
 2     1      A     1       1
 3     2      A     1       1
 4     2      A     1       1
 5     1      A     2       2
 6     1      A     2       2
 7     2      A     2       2
 8     2      A     2       2
 9     1      A     3       3
10     1      A     3       3
11     2      A     3       3
12     2      A     3       3
13     1      A     4       4
14     1      A     4       4
15     2      A     4       4
16     2      A     4       4
```